# Get list of Linux files recursively and direct output to file

Tags: files, search, text

I'm configuring software on Ubuntu for i2b2, and trying to find all of the relevant files on a CentOS image that I downloaded (path below) and am now running on Windows VMWare Player (free for download).  I'd like to create a file of the Linux file hierarchy recursively, for both CentOS and Ubuntu, so I can find the relevant files for each program (ie: JBoss, Java, Apache, Axis, Spring Web Framework, Oracle, etc..) and compare configuration.  I know how to do a similar thing in Windows by getting the output of all files.

Long story short, I just want a dump of all files in the Linux file system starting at the root folder, and save it to a file.

Here's the command in Windows to do this:

```
WINDOWS-COMMAND-PROMPT>dir /b /a /s >> files_on_windows.txt
```

Reference:

http://www.i2b2.org > Software (menu) > VMWare Image

Comment: Request from @Gilles to migrate to Unix & Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rough equivalent to your Windows command would use the [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command:

```
find / -xdev >files_on_linux.txt
```

I don't think it would be very useful for what you're doing. On Linux (both CentOS and Ubuntu), programs come in packages; if you want to have the same programs on Ubuntu and CentOS, then you should obtain a list of packages on the CentOS machine, and install the same packages on Ubuntu. On CentOS, you can list the installed packages with the following command (the `sed` step strips off version numbers, which are irrelevant here):

```
rpm -qa | sed 's/-[0-9]*//' | sort >centos_packages.txt
```

The bad news is that CentOS and Ubuntu use different package names, so you can't take this list and do the installation on Ubuntu. You can cut some of the work by ignoring any package called lib*something*, as these will be pulled in automatically by the programs that need them. Some of the package names will match one-for-one; you can install them as follows:

```
apt-get install $(grep -v '^lib' centos_packages.txt)
```

You can use the following command to see what packages are not installed or have a different name — it shows the lines that are present in `centos_packages.txt` but not in the output of `dpkg --get-selections`, which lists the installed (or selected-for-installation) packages on Ubuntu:

```
dpkg --get-selections | sort | comm -31 - centos_packages.txt
```

Additionally, there may be programs installed under `/usr/local` or `/opt` that do not come from the packaging system. You should be able to copy the files directly. You can do it this way:

```
cd /
sudo tar cjf usr_local.tar.bz2 opt usr/local
```

Copy the `usr_local.tgz` file to the new Linux system and unpack it:

```
cd /
sudo tar xjf usr_local.tar.bz2
```

Comment: This was very helpful!  Can I do the same thing, but only retrieve directories, and ignore files?

Comment: @MacGyver `find / -xdev -type d` lists only the directories. Something like `ls /bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin` might be more useful for your purpose though.